# How do I convert an array to a wide data frame in R?

Tags: arrays, r, dataframe

Let's say I have an array

```
arr = as.array(c(1.1,0.5,3.2,4.3,5.5,6.3,0.4))
```

I want to convert this into a data frame so I try:

```
df = as.data.frame(arr)
```

But this gives me a data frame with nrows = 7 and ncols = 1. I need a data frame with nrows = 1 and ncols = 7. I have tried doing `t(df)` but that would return a matrix.

I know there has to be a simple way to do this... thank you!

Comment: `as.data.frame(t(arr))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
arr = array(c(1.1,0.5,3.2,4.3,5.5,6.3,0.4), dim = c(1, 7))
as.data.frame(arr)

#   V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7
#1 1.1 0.5 3.2 4.3 5.5 6.3 0.4
```

Note, use `array` or `matrix`, not `as.array` or `as.matrix`.

---

[alistaire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4497050/alistaire) mentioned a good way

```
as.data.frame(t(c(1.1,0.5,3.2,4.3,5.5,6.3,0.4)))

#   V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7
#1 1.1 0.5 3.2 4.3 5.5 6.3 0.4
```

which will transform the `dim` for you automatically.

Comment: `arr` is an array, not a vector. `as.data.frame.list(arr)` will put an array into wide form directly, though that's somewhat inexplicable.

Answer (score 3):

If we need 7 column dataset, we can use `as.data.frame.list` on a `vector`

```
as.data.frame.list(c(1.1,0.5,3.2,4.3,5.5,6.3,0.4))
```

As @ZheyuanLi mentioned the above will append "X" as prefix for the column names.  We can change the column names in the `col.names` argument

```
as.data.frame.list(c(1.1,0.5,3.2,4.3,5.5,6.3,0.4), col.names = paste0("V", 1:7))
```

Or another option would be to have names for the `vector` elements

```
as.data.frame.list(setNames(c(1.1,0.5,3.2,4.3,5.5,6.3,0.4), paste0("V", 1:7)))
```

Comment: This option ----> as.data.frame.list(setNames(c(1.1,0.5,3.2,4.3,5.5,6.3,0.4), paste0("V", 1:7))) <----- worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: I might have an older version of R installed in the database since this ---> as.data.frame.list(c(1.1,0.5,3.2,4.3,5.5,6.3,0.4), col.names = paste0("V", 1:7)) <----- did not change the column names

Comment: @strv7 I am using R 3.3.0