# R linear model (lm) predict function with one single array

Tags: r, postgresql, lm, predict, plr

I have an `lm` model in R that I have trained and serialized. Inside a function, where I pass as input the model and a feature vector (one single array), I have:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lm_predict(
    feat_vec float[],
    model bytea
)
RETURNS float
AS
$$
    #R-code goes here.
    mdl <- unserialize(model)
    # class(feat_vec) outputs "array"
    y_hat <- predict.lm(mdl, newdata = as.data.frame.list(feat_vec))
    return (y_hat)
$$ LANGUAGE 'plr';
```

This returns the wrong `y_hat`!! I know this because this other solution works (the inputs to this function are still the model (in a bytearray) and one `feat_vec` (array)):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lm_predict(
    feat_vec float[],
    model bytea
)
RETURNS float
AS
$$
    #R-code goes here.
    mdl <- unserialize(model)
    coef = mdl$coefficients
    y_hat = coef[1] + as.numeric(coef[-1]%*%feat_vec)
    return (y_hat)
$$ LANGUAGE 'plr';
```

What am I doing wrong?? It is the same unserialized model, the first option should give me the right answer as well...

Comment: Is this R code? It looks like half python; colons don't work that way in R, nor does `return` or `+`.

Comment: Yes, it is R + pseudocode - you can ignore the function declaration
Actually - this is inside a PL/R function in Postgres but I didn't want to give focus on Postgres

Comment: ...so how is pseudocode returning a result, correct or not?

Comment: I have made some edits to my question, hopefully it is clear now. The first options returns a wrong number, whilst the second returns the correct prediction! I have no errors however

Comment: Better, but still not answerable without [a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have added the function calls

Comment: It is R inside PostgreSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be the use of `newdata = as.data.frame.list(feat_vec)`. As discussed in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39522955/4891738), this returns ugly column names. While when you call `predict`, `newdata` must have column names consistent with covariates names in your model formula. You should get some warning message when you call `predict`.

```
## example data
set.seed(0)
x1 <- runif(20)
x2 <- rnorm(20)
y <- 0.3 * x1 + 0.7 * x2 + rnorm(20, sd = 0.1)

## linear model
model <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2)

## new data
feat_vec <- c(0.4, 0.6)
newdat <- as.data.frame.list(feat_vec)
#  X0.4 X0.6
#1  0.4  0.6

## prediction
y_hat <- predict.lm(model, newdata = newdat)
#Warning message:
#'newdata' had 1 row but variables found have 20 rows
```

What you need is

```
newdat <- as.data.frame.list(feat_vec,
                             col.names = attr(model$terms, "term.labels"))
#   x1  x2
#1 0.4 0.6

y_hat <- predict.lm(model, newdata = newdat)
#        1 
#0.5192413
```

This is the same as what you can compute manually:

```
coef = model$coefficients
unname(coef[1] + sum(coef[-1] * feat_vec))
#[1] 0.5192413
```

Comment: I don't get to see warning messages when calling R from Postgres... But something is definitely wrong

Comment: thank you for your answer. I really appreciate it.
It is still not working for me though, y_hat returns always the same result while the "manual" computation returns correct predictions. I don't understand why :/
Why do I need to include the col.names?? Is that really important?

Comment: This solved my issue when working with randomForest... thanks! I still get the weird behavior with lm but happy I got it to work with another regression model and exactly the same code!